# How can I make the taskbar icon for my app move to the same display as the app?

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-10, taskbar

Starting with Windows 8, there is a taskbar settings called `Show taskbar buttons on` where the user can control where the taskbar buttons are displayed when multiple displays are being used. How can I get my application to obey the `Taskbar where window is open` setting instead of always displaying on only the main taskbar?

The app in question is written in VB6 but I imagine this question might apply to other older frameworks as well.

Comment: Do you have multiple forms visible at the same time? What happens if you hide and show a form, does its taskbar button move?

Comment: @Anders Single form. If I move it to another display, hide it, and then show it again, it will appear on the corresponding taskbar.

So, certainly I could work around this by detecting when the form is moved and then programmatically hide and show it. Just wondering if there is a more "automatic" way to get Windows to handle the taskbar for me.